# content management tool for responsive site support IE, chrome AND smartphone(Ios and android)

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, sitefinity, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-6

We need to create responsive Content management site that will run on all browser and smartphone ( Android and IOS)

Is dotnentnuke support android and IOS ?

Please let me know CMS tool available in market which can be use to create responsive site for IE, chrome,Firefox, Safari AND smartphone (Android, Ios)

Answer (score 1):

Sitefinity does include an add-on for responsive design and for building mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Responsiveness is not based on CMS. It is based on the template you are using. Find a good responsive template for any CMS you want to use and it will work fine on any platform.

Comment: Not entirely true. Yes, you can make virtually any CMS incorporate responsive design through the use of a responsive design templates. However, some content management systems supply there own responsive templates and include additional features such as visual page designers that support responsive design. Preview modes for different devices. And most importantly tech support.

Comment: One situation in which you might prefer to use responsive design templates would be if you wanted to develop the same responsive design strategy & techniques for both your content manager sites as well as sites that do not use a content manager.